# Issue with API after 6.2 update

Tags: rest-api, api

I have a python program that automatically updates pages/posts on my websites.
Recently I started getting this error only on the websites with 6.2 update:

```
400 - Bad Request | Your browser sent a request this server could not understand.
```

Here is how I connect to the API:

```
username="example"
url ='https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2'
password='example'
if post:
    url += '/posts/'
else:
    url += '/pages/'
creds = username + ':' + password
cred_token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())

header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + cred_token.decode('utf-8')}
post = {
    'content' : content
    }
blog = requests.post(url + postid, headers=header, json=post)
```

My question is did anything change in the API? why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, no. Is the content definitely valid? Is there anything in the server logs with more detail?

Comment: @Rup thank you, no not really, today it started working again, without me changing anything, weird!